# Error while trying to send data from form to MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have some problems while trying to send data from form to mysql database using php.I know how to fix this when i set form action to anothen page (`<form action="example.php>`, but i want that all procces stay on one page.
WHen i run my php script and enter name in both of fields and go send, only url page changes, nothing else.Hope u can help me.Thanks

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo"Error connecting to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['input_send']))
{
$name=($_POST['input_name']);
$lastname=($_POST['input_lastname']);
$insert="INSERT INTO test_mysql (name, lastname) VALUES ('$name', $lastname)";
echo"record added";
}
?>
<form action="" action="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="input_name"/>
Last name: <input type="text" name="input_lastname"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="input_send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: and the error message is ? Error connecting to database ??

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is exactly? It's not clear..

Comment: THere is no error message.Only problem is that when i click on send only url of the page changes to `http://localhost/form_2/guestbook.php?input_name=myname&input_lastname=mylastname&input_send=send`

Comment: you said error in your question ?? are you getting `echo"record added";` ??

Comment: **SQL INJECTION ALERT**

Comment: I'am sorry, i wrote it bad.I wanted to say that when i click "send" nothing happens, there is no echo"record added" and only url of the page is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
  $insert="INSERT INTO test_mysql (name, lastname) VALUES ('$name', $lastname)";
```

to

```
 mysqli_query("INSERT INTO test_mysql (name, lastname) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname')");
```

and this

```
action="post"
```

to

```
method="post"
```

and escape your variables like that:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input_name']);
$lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input_lastname']);
```

Comment: I made that all changes but when i click send it says "record added" but it wasn't added to database.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you typed

```
action="post"
```

instead of

```
method="post"
```

Without a method specified, PHP will fall back to GET. 
Hence your `isset($_POST)` will return false and you are not seeing 'record added'

Another error, as pointed out by echo_ME is that you are not submitting the MySQL Query to the Database:

```
$insert="INSERT INTO test_mysql (name, lastname) VALUES ('$name', $lastname)";
```

With the function [mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query) you can perform your query:

```
mysqli_query($insert);
```

As noted by others you should escape your variables to prevent [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?=echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method='post'>
```

You can take info about the page url from your server.

It basicly action to the same page, i mean itself.